# Sum all values in each column bash

Tags: bash, csv, sum, multiple-columns

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
ID_X,1,2,7,8
ID_Y,6,9,3,5
ID_Z,7,12,4,4
```

My goal is to create a csv file with the sum of all the values in each single column (from second column on), so in this case, that file will look like this:

```
SUM,14,23,14,17
```

So far, I am able to do it for one column at a time using awk. For instance, for the first column with numbers:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} ; {sum+=$2} END {print sum}' test.txt
14
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am looking for?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

   ```
   echo -n SUM,; datamash -t,  sum 2,3,4,5 < file.csv
   ```
2. Using [`numsum`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

   ```
   printf 'SUM%.0s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n' `numsum -s, -c  file.csv`
   ```

   or, if the number of columns in *file.csv* is variable:

   ```
   numsum -s, -c  file.csv | sed 's/^0/SUM/;y/ /,/'
   ```

Output:

```
SUM,14,23,14,17
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.
With awk you could say:

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {sum[i]+=$i} len=NF}
END {$1="SUM"; for (i=2; i<=len; i++) $i=sum[i]; print}
' file.csv
```