# Print sum of rows and other row value for each column in awk

Tags: csv, awk, sum, multiple-columns

I have a csv file structured as the one below:

```
             |  Taiwan  |       |   US      |   
             |  ASUS    |   MSI |   DELL    |   HP
            ------------------------------------------
    CPU      |  50      |   49  |   43      |   65
    GPU      |  60      |   64  |   75      |   54
    HDD      |  75      |   70  |   65      |   46
    RAM      |  60      |   79  |   64      |   63
    assembled|  235     |   244 |   254     |   269
```

and I have to use an awk script to print a comparison between the sum of prices of the individual computer pieces (rows 3 to 6) "versus" the assembled computer price (row 7) displaying also the country each brand comes from. The printed result in the terminal should be something like:

```
Taiwan      Asus    245     235
Taiwan      MSI     262     244
US          DELL    247     254
US          HP      228     269
```

Where the third column is the sum of CPU, GPU, HDD and RAM prices and the fourth column is the price same value seen in row 7 per each computer brand.

So far I have been able to sum the individual columns transforming the solution provided at the post I link below, but I don´t know how I could display the result I want in the desired format. Could anyone help me with this? I´m a bit desperate at this point.

[Sum all values in each column bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49970877/sum-all-values-in-each-column-bash)

This is the content of the original csv file represented at the top of this message:

```
,Taiwan,,US,
,ASUS,MSI,DELL,HP
CPU,50,49,43,65
GPU,60,64,75,54
HDD,75,70,65,46
RAM,60,79,64,63
assembled,235,244,254,269
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Show us the CSV contents so we can help you write a tool to operate on those contents, not how the CSV looks when displayed as a table by some tool or how you imagine it to be laid out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I edited the original message and added the content of the example file, please let me know if you mean something else that I´m totally missing.

Comment: Nope, that was what I meant, thanks for adding that. The only thing you should still add to make this a good question (see [ask]) is your own attempt to solve the problem yourself since the intent of this forum is to help people with their coding, not to just provide code to solve a problem, so questions without code often get closed by the community as off topic. Oh and it's OK to provide links to additional, optional information  but make sure everything we need is in the question and it's good standalone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
NR == 2 {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        corp[i] = (p[i] == "" ? p[i-1] : p[i]) OFS $i
    }
}
NR > 2 {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        tot[i] += p[i]
    }
}
{ split($0,p) }
END {
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        print corp[i], tot[i], p[i]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Taiwan  ASUS    245     235
Taiwan  MSI     262     244
US      DELL    247     254
US      HP      228     269
```